Radiator Covers - MDF or Plywood?
3/4 MDF or 3/4 Plywood?
I'm building a few custom radiator covers that will be painted and am deciding on the wood I will use. These are on a hot water system (Not Steam), and they almost never produce any type of moisture, so using MDF doesn't seem like it will cause a problem.  I've seen plenty of people using MDF, but I wanted to ask what you all think.
MDF pro's are that its easy enough to work with, is cheaper, shouldn't warp
Plywood/Hardwood, more expensive, possibly more durable, but may warp over time.
I'm building in a method where it will not be restricting the heat. I know some say never cover a radiator, but in my case its happening in  the most efficient design possible to allow the heat to escape.
MDF? Plywood? Hardwood? Help me decide.

Really personal choice. "White wood" (cheap) frames supporting metal radiator grilles at top/front/sides are a classic choice and are what's standard in my area. Radiator covers can also be purchased preconstructed.

MDF is normally used in applications where paint is the finish for the reasons you have mentioned. For the rare occasional wetness, be sure the inside is also painted (doesn't need to look nice, just seal it with something - you can get free leftover paint at some transfer stations, since the color does not matter, at all.)

My local county has a "solid waste transfer station" which is also the recycling dropoff for things that don't get recycled in the weekly pickup - e.g., electronics, hazmat, paint, light bulbs, batteries, etc. But I wonder how common the "transfer station" term really is. If my county didn't call it a "transfer station" then my first thought would be: "why should I go to where there are multiple train lines that you can switch from one to another - do people really leave paint there?"

No transporting red paint on the green line, no blue paint on the yellow line... With the passing of "the dump" the "transfer station" is quite common in the US.

In some towns there's an explicit reuse shed. Point is, ugly old paint is easy to find. Heck, ugly new paint is often available cheap at paint stores when someone got the tinting wrong and the store has to replace the first batch  Another good source for cheap paint in random colors is architectural recycling centers such as Habitat For Humanity's "Re/Stores"
